# I have a function that give numbers in 2 arrays

Tags: c

I have a function that give numbers in 2 arrays but the second array does not take all the given numbers. Any ideas what's happening?

I try this

```
struct array
{
    int (*list)[N];
    int (*mlist)[N];
};

int input(struct array x){
    int i, j;
    printf("Give the intiger numbrs for the first array: ");
    for(i = 0; i< N; i++){
        scanf("%d", *(x.list+i));
    }

    printf("Give the intiger numbrs for the second array: ");
    for(j = 0; j< N; j++){
        scanf("%d", *(x.mlist+j));
    }
   }

int main(){
    struct array x;

    input(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your structure contains two pointers to arrays, but you never allocated any memory for them.

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas whats happen?

**Missing assignments**

```
int main(){
  struct array x; // At this point x and its members are uninitialized.
```

Later

```
int input(struct array x){
  // x here is a copy of the junk passed to it from main().

  int i, j;
  printf("Give the intiger numbrs for the first array: ");
  for(i = 0; i< N; i++) {

    // x.list still has not been yet assigned.
    // So `x.list+i` is a junk calculation. 
    // Undefined behavior (UB) 
    scanf("%d", *(x.list+i));  
  }
```